# Manifest Folder in new android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, manifest

After creating a new application with android studio. 
I see a manifest file in MyApplication/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.
I changed the version code and version name in this file and tried to display them dynamically. However they were still displaying 1, and 1.0.

I looked into the hardisk and Saw a folder in the path:
C:...\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml

using an external editor I changed the values in this file However still getting version 1 on my logs.

Where can I find this Manifest folder/file through android studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version code and version name are generally set in your application module's **build.gradle** file. If there are values there, they override what's in your manifest file.

The file you found in an "intermediates" folder is part of the build process, and if you modify it directly, your changes will quickly be lost when that file is rebuilt.

Comment: thanks a lot. I wonder if you have encountered any link/book that explains the new android structure in details.

Comment: The official docs are at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide